# Video Stream from Python to Java Android Studio

Tags: python, java, android-studio, sockets, video-streaming

I have a problem when I get the Base64 String from a Python socket. The video input is my webcam and I need to show the image in an Android App using ImageView. I only get one frame from the socket to Android app, the log in Android studio only prints one base64 String,and then 3 - 5 seconds later, the python app freezes. I'm noob in Python lol.

```
from numpy.core import numeric
import requests
import cv2
import pickle
import socket
import struct
import numpy as np
import imutils
import base64
from pyzbar import pyzbar


def main():
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    host_ip = "192.168.100.20"
    print('IP DEL HOST:', host_ip)
    port = 9999
    socket_address = (host_ip, port)
    # BIND-PROCESO
    server_socket.bind(socket_address)

    # COMENZAMOS A ESCUCHAR LOS PUERTOS
    server_socket.listen(5)
    print("LUGAR DE ESCUCHA: ", socket_address)

    try:
        while True:    
            client_socket, addr = server_socket.accept()
            print('CONEXIÓN ENTRANTE:', addr)
            WIDTH = 400
            while True:
                try:
                    _,img = vid.read()
                    frame = imutils.resize(img,width=WIDTH)
                    #read_barcodes(frame)
                    cv2.imshow("Android_cam", frame)
                    encoded,buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpeg',frame,[cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY,50])
                    message = base64.b64encode(buffer)
                    size = len(message)
                    print(size)
                    strSize = str(size) + "\n"
                    client_socket.sendto(strSize.encode('utf-8'),addr)
                    client_socket.sendto(message,addr)
                    #this is my idea to separate the next size with the base64 string
                    client_socket.sendto(("\nhappy face\n").encode('utf-8'),addr)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
                    raise Exception(e)
                if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
                    break
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Finalizado')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And the Java client is the next:

```
 public class actualizar extends AsyncTask<String, Bitmap, String> {

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            Log.i("hola","Running");
            try {
                boolean XD = true;
                byte conteo = 0;
                while(XD){
                    socket = new Socket(IP_HOST,PORT);
                    conteo = 0;
                    BufferedReader mBufferIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                    String xxx = mBufferIn.readLine();

                    int size = Integer.parseInt(xxx);
                    String next = mBufferIn.readLine();

                    InputStream targetStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(next.getBytes());
                    Log.i("Printing image",next.length()+" ::: " + size + " ::: " + targetStream.available());

                    Log.i("substring", next.substring(size,next.length()));
                    String newNext = next.substring(0,size);
                    int maxLogSize = 1000;
                    //showing the base64 string
    
                    for(int i = 0; i <= next.length() / maxLogSize; i++) {
                        int start = i * maxLogSize;
                        int end = (i+1) * maxLogSize;
                        end = end > next.length() ? next.length() : end;
                        Log.v("OOOOOO", next.substring(start, end));
                    }


                    byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(next, Base64.DEFAULT);
                    Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
                    this.publishProgress(decodedByte);
                    String happyFace = mBufferIn.readLine();
                    Log.i("Happy face?: ",happyFace);
                    if(targetStream == null)
                        XD = false;

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            return null;
        }
        //setting the bitmap to imageView 
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Bitmap... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            imgShow.setImageBitmap(values[0]);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

The

```
BufferedReader mBufferIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
```

needs to be out of the `while`.